# How do I destroy the KonvaJs animation from the memory footprint?

Tags: javascript, konvajs, memory-footprint

I am trying to completely remove the KonvaJS animation from memory. There is a way to stop the animation, but I can't destroy it.

```
var anim = new Konva.Animation(function (frame) {
   // some stuff
}, layer);

anim.start();

anim.destroy();
```

How do I completely destroy the animation?

Answer (score 0):

Stopping animation should be enough to remove it from memory if you no longer use it.

Comment: It's not removed from the memory, as mentioned in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76533893/why-react-application-using-more-memory-footprint